# Why do we use “wichtigen” instead of “wichtige” in this case?

Tags: adjective-ending

I am now watching a [German learning programme](https://learngerman.dw.com/en/partnersuche/l-38481290) by DW. At 1:13 there is a line:

> Ich habe alle wichtigen Formulare ausgefüllt

According to my understanding, this belongs to the “adjective endings after no article – plural” case, so it should be *wichtige* instead of *wichtigen*. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Wen oder was habe ich aus gefüllt? Alle wichtigen Formulare! Das Formular - sächlich https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:wichtig

Comment: The word *alle* is a definite determiner as *die*.

Comment: Here is the declension table thats gonna help you with this and many other questions :) https://www.germanveryeasy.com/adjective-declension keywords: German adjective declension

Comment: Any reason for reopening a "conjugation table" question?

Comment: @Dan It's not a  "conjugation table" question. OP's question comes from not understanding that *alle* is a determiner like *die*. It's got a good answer explaining this.

Comment: @PiedPiper, but it is. top result in google, keywords:adjective conjugation German https://www.germanveryeasy.com/adjective-declension under the "weak declension" section. Are you SERIOUS? Should we now wait for 7 more questions to this very topic, because OP wouldn't know about "manche" or "welche" or "einige" or "keine"? One question for each word (all from a simple decl. table!) or what?  Things like that are one of the reasons WHY here is not a substitute to conjugation and declension tables!

Answer (score 4):

"alle" is a determiner, like an article "die".

"alle _ Formulare" is akkusativ (contrast dativ: "allen"). The word at the second position, "wichtig-", inflects differently. I cannot quite explain why. One notable difference is that a bare "wichtige Formulare" would be indefinite, as would be colloquial "wenige falsche Freunde", properly "wenige der wichtigen Fragen". Compare e.g. Fr "toutes des questiones signifiques", En "all the important questions" vs "toutes question", "all questions". Whereas "?Alle der Fragen" would be less likely and poor style, though "all' die [diese] Fragen" is not rare.

Consequently, "alle wichtigen Fragen" is equivalent to "alle der wichtigen Fragen" in a certain context. [alle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alle) should index it as *quantifier*; They call it "pronoun", same difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich habe *alle wichtigen* Formulare ausgefüllt.

As you already figured out, the adjective *wichtig* should be plural, to be precise: accusive plural just like the noun *Formulare*. Now, we only need to decide, whether it should be [declined](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Flexion:wenig#wenig_(Deklination)_(Deutsch)) strongly (*wichtige*) or weakly (*wichtigen*).

Strong declension (**S**) appears when there is no article or other word declined like an adjective. Weak declension (**W**) appears in connection with a definite article. For instance:

> - Ich habe *alle*<sub>(**S**)</sub> Formulare ausgefüllt.
> - Ich habe *wichtige*<sub>(**S**)</sub> Formulare ausgefüllt.
> - Ich habe *die wichtigen*<sub>(**W**)</sub> Formulare ausgefüllt.
>
> <sup>(Notice that *alles* does not occur in a weakly declined form, which is why a corresponding example wouldn't make sense.)</sup>

There is also a third type, *mixed declension*, which appears when there is yet another adjective, or a word that is [declined like an adjective](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Deklination#Artikelw%C3%B6rter_und_Adjektive), such as the indefinite pronoun *alles*. In our example, *alles* is declined strongly whereas *wichtig* is declined weakly:

> Ich habe *alle<sub>(**S**)</sub> wichtigen<sub>(**W**)</sub>* Formulare ausgefüllt.